# Can't figure out sql join

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I'm using nextcloud to track data via the forms app, the table **oc_forms_v2_submissions** contains the entries:

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_forms_v2_submissions` WHERE `form_id` = 3;
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
| id | form_id | user_id                                    | timestamp  |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
|  8 |       3 | anon-user-96684f301d22e7be44f07780a9bffe06 | 1663789158 |
|  9 |       3 | anon-user-a1eaa4f939b59e00b403c046410788aa | 1663835954 |
| 10 |       3 | anon-user-440d0dbe9c107492b6ec1a06d98004a8 | 1663942458 |
+----+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+
```

the second table is **oc_forms_v2_answers**

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_forms_v2_answers`;
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| id | submission_id | question_id | text                  |
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 10 |             8 |           7 | foo                   |
| 11 |             9 |           7 | bar                   |
| 12 |            10 |           7 | foo                   |
+----+---------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

So basically i need to the take all the id entries from table submissions and match them with submission_id from answers **and** I want to have the data from the **text** column.

```
SELECT oc_forms_v2_submissions.id as submission_id
FROM `oc_forms_v2_submissions` 
RIGHT  JOIN `oc_forms_v2_answers` ON submission_id=oc_forms_v2_answers.submission_id;
```

This is all i could come up with so far but that returns only the submission_id field and everything triplicated :-D

```
+---------------+
| submission_id |
+---------------+
|             8 |
|             8 |
|             8 |
|             9 |
|             9 |
|             9 |
|            10 |
|            10 |
|            10 |
+---------------+
```

Edit:

The updated query still does not get me the field from oc_forms_answers:

```
SELECT oc_forms_v2_submissions.id as submission_id
FROM `oc_forms_v2_submissions`
RIGHT JOIN `oc_forms_v2_answers` ON oc_forms_v2_submissions.id=oc_forms_v2_answers.submission_id where form_id="3";
```

Answer (score 2):

that is because you are comparing to identical columns, you need in the ON Clause, the link columns of **both** tables

Also you can use alias, to  reduce the typing time

The RIGHT JOIN would also combine all answers with thes ubmission, but you you will never have more submission as answer, so a LEFT JOIN would gove ou all submissions even if there is no answer

```
SELECT oc_forms_v2_submissions.id as submission_id
FROM `oc_forms_v2_submissions` 
LEFT JOIN `oc_forms_v2_answers` ON oc_forms_v2_submissions.id=oc_forms_v2_answers.submission_id;
```

Comment: Ok that was seriously meh. However the updated query still does not get me the "text" field from oc_forms_answers.

Comment: which update query? i don't see any attempt and i don't see what should be updated. see if you can aument https://dbfiddle.uk/L797x0Vm and post the new link

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (just update the correct naming of columns and tables)

```
SELECT s.id as submission_id, a.txt FROM submissions s 
LEFT JOIN answers a 
ON s.id=a.submission_id;
```

You can check this here in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mUphAfQiB7dAnAr6WCEmgF/0). I've used your info for creating a DB, so WHERE clause is missing but all the rest should give you results you're after.